# Ubuntu 18.04 constantly freezing after a few days

Tags: 18.04

I have an ubuntu 18 server that I run some vm's / lxd containers on.

from time to time I can't access my stuff remotely and it turns out that when i physically go to the box, lights are on however nothing i do "wakes" the pc up.

any suggestions on how to start troubleshooting?

Comment: Look in /var/log/syslog for events and clues that occur just before or during the system's unresponsiveness.

Comment: I have a KRON that runs every minute and the only thing interesting in the logs is a complete stop at 17:02 yesterday  until i rebooted this morning at 06:53

`Oct 13 17:09:10 SERVER kernel: [47877.081174] audit: type=1400 audit(1539450550.664:143): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="lxd-piholeunifi_</var/lib/lxd>" name="/bin/" pid=28243 comm="(ionclean)" flags="ro, remount, bind"
Oct 14 06:53:22 SERVER systemd-modules-load[1031]: Inserted module 'lp'`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of burying important information in comments.